# setting a variable equal to the value in the adjacent column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that i need to use to get to the full name of the object from the abbreviation in order to search for it in a different dataframe.
this is the first few lines of the simple dataframe. it lists all of the national parks in the US. I need this for input menus and decision trees in the program.

[image]

In bad pseudo code I need code that is like.

```
my`_var = next line over from park_abbrev`in df
```

so if park_abbrev = DENA then my_var = Denali National Park and Preserve

I need this because I use the initials for user input and that leads to this function, which is picking trails from a separate very large dataframe depending on the difficulty level the user selects.This dataframe only has the full name of the park, not the abbreviation, and i need that to get only the trails in the park of interest.
thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the the `park_names`s if the `park_abbrev` is `DENA` using `df.loc`:

```
df.loc[df['park_abbrev']=='DENA','park_name']
```

Comment: this could be close, but please let me try to explain a little better. the park_abbrev is a variable from another function as well as a column in the dataframe. so i need to pull in the park_abbrev  as a global variable and set that equal to the full name in the next column. it will not always be 'DENA' . In this case can i just use the variable park_abbrev in place of 'DENA' in this code? I will try it. thank you for the help.

Comment: yes, that seemed to work. now i just need to get the relationship query working. thank you!